# XPath of French Characters

Tags: java, string, selenium, cucumber

I have a HTML code

```
<a id="cmplobremoveTéléphonie+default" class="cmpLOB-remove-btn" onclick="cmpLobRemoveButtonHandler(event, this);" style="text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:void(0)">Retirer</a>
```

I need to click on the element with xpath as `@id='cmplobremoveTéléphonie+default'`.

In Cucumber, I have a feature file step as

```
When Click on remove Button and click on confirm "Téléphonie"
```

The corresponding method is,

```
@When("^Click on remove Button and click on confirm \"([^\"]*)\"")
    public void remove_Button(String remove) throws Throwable {
        String remove_Required = "cmplobremove" +remove +"+default";
        driver.baseDriver.findElement(By.id(remove_Required)).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.baseDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Confirm")).click();
        log.info(remove + "is removed");
    }
```

When I try to execute the above step, I'm getting the following NullPointerException,

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"groupIcon+default+T?l?phonie"}
```

It seems the french text cannot be passed in a similar way to English Text as a string argument. As you can see that Téléphonie is mentioned as T?l?phonie. Seems something to do with UTF-8/UTF-16.

Solutions are appreciated on how to parse the value.

Comment: You can try using the unicode for `é` which is `\u00E9`, like so "T\u00E9l\u00E9phonie"

Comment: Hi Daniel, I get the same error. `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"groupIcon+default+T\\u00E9l\\u00E9phonie"} ` We need to find a way to decode the argument that's being passed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get if you print out `remove` string ? Not sure why it's not recognizing the letter, will try to get something runing similar to your case.

Comment: Hi @DanielFintinariu - it's the same "T\u00E9l\u00E9phonie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the default file encoder is ANSI for windows. I have changed the encoder to UTF-8 and now it's working without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

try altenative for identifying that element as below using:

```
 driver.baseDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Retirer')]").click();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 driver.baseDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Confirm")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Kushal, I can create an alternate xpath. I just want to understand how to parse french characters.